# Azure AD Graph vs Microsoft Graph App Authorization Tokens

Tags: azure, graph, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

i have an application currently using the Azure AD Graph API. I would like to start migrating the app to Microsoft Graph. However, i would like to reuse the bearer tokens for hitting both the Azure AD Graph API and Microsoft Graph API.

how can i accomplish this? as currently it seems as if the apps must be registered in different portals for the different api's respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it seems as if the apps must be registered in different portals for the different api's respectively

This is not consistent with my experience. I have registered my Application in Azure Active Directory.

Using the Azure portal, I am able to get permissions to both the Microsoft Graph Api and the Windows Azure Active Directory API.

[image]

> i would like to reuse the bearer tokens for hitting both the Azure AD Graph API and Microsoft Graph API.

You cannot use the same token for both the Azure AD Graph API and Microsoft Graph API.

In my code, I receive an access token via the following call:

```
AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                authorizationCode,
                redirectUri,
                CreateClientCredential(),
                resourceString
            );
```

The `resourceString` parameter is either `https://graph.windows.net/` for the AD Graph API, or `https://graph.microsoft.com` for the Microsoft Graph API.

They are distinct resources, so you must manage two tokens, applying the appropriate token for each API call.

Comment: this actually make a lot of sense. thinking of Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph as different resources, in terms of how oAuth works.

I didn't want my users to grant me another consent for another API as i migrate the app to Microsoft Graph. but, it makes sense.

as for the app registration. i am likely not doing something right.

thanks andrew!